# how to install shopify app using node API?

Tags: node.js, api, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I have a shopify app(ggfi) in my admin account . I have a website to sell custom gif too.

What I want :

1. when a new user login from my website to shopify , I want to install my app(ggfi) to their shopify dash board , without them clicking "install app" button .

I could not find any node API documentations to do this from my API side .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do, but if you want to install an app without having to click a button, you can just redirect them to your app path and insert their shop in the query like this:

```
https://yourapp.com/auth?shop=theirshop.myshopify.com
```

They will have to authenticate again and grant permissions to your app.

This will work on my app built with Shopify CLI, but you have to check how the redirect process works on your app.